# Error in SpEL while using Spring-Integration Gemfire support

Tags: expression, spring-integration, spring-el, gemfire

I am using Spring-Integration 3.0 and Spring-Integration Gemfire support. I wanted my inbound-channel-adapter to pick up the objects in cache as payload based on SpEL expression. I have written a custom expression evaluator class to check the properties of payload to select by the input adapter. 
The class code is as below:

```
@Component
public class GraphMatchingUtil {

public static boolean evaluate(NodeGraph nodeGraph){
    if(nodeGraph.getLastProcessedTS()!=null){

        if(nodeGraph.getLastProcessedTS().getTime() -  DateTimeUtil.createTimestamp().getTime() > 100000){
            return true;
        }
    }
    else{
        if(nodeGraph.getCreateTS().getTime() -  DateTimeUtil.createTimestamp().getTime() > 100000){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

And the configuration code is as below

```
<int:spel-function id="match" class="com.equ.util.GraphMatchingUtil" method="evaluate(com.equ.bo.NodeGraph)"/>
<int-gfe:inbound-channel-adapter id="graphadapter" channel="reconchannel" region="cacheRegion" cache-events="CREATED, UPDATED" expression="@match(payload)==true"/>
```

However I am getting the below error after executing this code:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'graphadapter': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'payloadExpression' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 6): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lparen(()'
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
     PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'payloadExpression' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 6): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lparen(()'
```

Can anyone help me in understanding whats wrong with it?

After replacing @ with # I got this error:

```
   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'payload' cannot be found on object of type 'com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EntryEventImpl'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `payload` in that expression - there is no message yet; that expression is "Expression to be evaluated to produce a value for the payload.", per the XSD documentation.

We should explain more clearly in the documentation that the root object for this expression is a Gemfire `EntryEvent` ([javadocs here](http://www.gemstone.com/docs/current/product/docs/japi/com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/EntryEvent.html)).

If you want to pass the entire event into your function, use `#root`.

`expression="#match(#root)==true"`

or you could do something like

`expression="#match(key, oldValue, newValue)==true"`

Comment: Reference documentation updated: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/gemfire.html#gemfire-inbound

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is around the wrong reference to the SpEL function. Should be

```
expression="#match(payload)==true"
```

I meand the simbol `#` instead of `@`. Please, take a look into [SpEL Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)

The `@` is for bean reference, but `#` is for SpEL-function.

Comment: Where is error ? Just update your question with that new state

Comment: Hi, I had ried using # in place of @. I was getting the following exception:
    org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'payload' cannot be found on object of type 'com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.EntryEventImpl'